# Python docstring convention for private properties

Tags: python

Is it necessary to write a docstring for private properties? https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/ says that "Docstrings are not necessary for non-public methods, but you should have a comment that describes what the method does. This comment should appear after the def line." Does this also include private properties?

Comment: You document not because someone said so, but to make code easy to read and understand. If prop is self explanatory or plain simple and clear then most likely can be ommited, esp. there are some methods related to it. If unsure, just comment won't hurt

Answer (score 0):

Generally in Python, you should strive for your documentation to be cohesive. Match the style with the rest of your project. You could opt to not document the property at all, use comments only, or write documentation like you did elsewhere.

I personally would suggest the last one and remembering to maintain cohesion.